# Eclipse won't launch because `reload maven project has encountered a p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m`

Tags: linux, eclipse, maven, centos, m2eclipse

When I try to start Eclipse Luna in CentOS 7, I get the following dialog box:

[image]

How can I resolve this and get eclipse to start?

Comment: Before deleting your Eclipse workspace `.metadata`, try building the Maven projects from the command line - it could be a problem in your `pom.xml` files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I removed .metada from workspace and reimported the maven projects as quick and dirty solution. You loose your Eclipse settings, you can try to play with metadata.

Comment: I cannot confirm your answer because this is an old post and I have moved on to other things. But thank you and +1 for replying to this old post.

Comment: Don't blow await all your workspace config. Use instead this answer a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13545818/4662899

Comment: Eclipse gave me a StackOverflowException instead of NullPointerException. This answer does not resolve the problem.

Comment: @Nathan StackOverflowException could be caused by a circular reference in your `pom.xml` files. Try building the projects on the command line (`mvn clean compile`).

Comment: @ThomasTaylor I highly doubt it was due to a circular reference in my `pom.xml`.  But, since it is no longer a problem I can't try out your idea.  I do not remember what I did to solve the problem.  I probably continued with more Google searches and eventually something worked.

Answer (score 54):

Instead of deleting the whole .metadata folder, just delete the file .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi"
You need to make sure to quit eclipse first, then remove this file and start eclipse again.

Error will be gone.

Comment: Thank you and +1 for giving people a different approach to try.

Comment: awesome solution saved my settings of eclipse as well
:) +1

Comment: +1 That worked for me.  However, in my case eclipse froze in background after this error.  I had to open the task manager, kill the process, go to .metadata, remove the .lock file before restarting eclipse.

Comment: Thank you, it works. In my case it also leads me to a new error :  "workspace is in use or cannot be created" that you can solve using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489322/eclipse-says-workspace-in-use-or-cannot-be-created-chose-a-different-one-ho)

Comment: Over a year after this was posted it helped me too.  I did lose some layout settings, but those are much easier things to fix than not being able to even start eclipse.

Comment: weird (because it seems that helps everyone), but it didn't work in my case. I ended up deleting whole .metadata

Comment: Eclipse gave me a StackOverflowException instead of NullPointerException. This answer does not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

For me it was enough just to remove the whole `<persistedState />` tag in

```
<workspace folder>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi
```

Comment: I started to go down this road because it seemed maybe I would save more of my settings by doing this.  However I had over 50 persistedState tags and it just wasn't worth sorting all that out.  I ended up using the recommendation by @Amanpreet-Kaur instead.

Comment: Eclipse gave me a StackOverflowException instead of NullPointerException.  This answer does not resolve the problem.