# Unable to start eclipse workspace by "Reload maven Project" Error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I Closed `eclipse` unfortunately when create and updating maven dependencies so after that unable to start the eclipse workspace and getting **"Unable to load Maven Project"** error
[image]

i could see below error log

```
 !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2016-03-06 00:18:32.977
 !MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "reload maven project".
 !STACK 0
 java.lang.NullPointerException
  at       org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.configureExecutionRequest(ProjectRegistryManager.java:864)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.createExecutionContext(ProjectRegistryManager.java:962)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.execute(ProjectRegistryManager.java:956)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.readProjectWithDependencies(ProjectRegistryManager.java:811)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.create(ProjectRegistryManager.java:191)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.MavenProjectManager.create(MavenProjectManager.java:80)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.actions.SelectionUtil.getMavenProject(SelectionUtil.java:259)
at org.eclipse.m2e.editor.pom.MavenPomEditor.readMavenProject(MavenPomEditor.java:729)
at org.eclipse.m2e.editor.pom.MavenPomEditor$5.run(MavenPomEditor.java:1050)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31080665/eclipse-wont-launch-because-reload-maven-project-has-encountered-a-proble-m) seems to be the same.
See if it helps.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31080665/eclipse-wont-launch-because-reload-maven-project-has-encountered-a-proble-m

Answer (score 0):

try to start eclipse in clean mode (eclipse -clean)

you can see also: http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Frunning_eclipse.htm

Answer (score 0):

Delete .metadata folder under your workspace.

Comment: This will basically delete all your project settings, your project will be empty.