# what does Maven -> Update Project... exactly?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, command-line

I am getting really frustrated about this one:

I am using an maven project, using jdbc with *eclipselink*. `mvn install` works as intended. Until I have to change the PW in the persistence.xml. When I do an `mvn clean` and afterwards `mvn install` the project is broken and the wrong (old) persistence.xml is still in use. In eclipse I have to do `maven -> update project` (using m2e addon) and `mvn install` works suddenly again.

**Now my problem:** On the deployment server I am using command line scripting and I found no `mvn XYZ` equivalent for the m2e functionality...

Is there some equivalent?

**Explicit scenario:**

I am developing on my local machine (osx/win7) in an maven project imported in eclipse. I have a JPA Persistence interface which encapsulate the database connection which is realized via *eclipselink*. I can deploy locally (`mvn install`) but after I run `mvn clean` and change the password in `persistence.xml` `mvn install` isn't possible anymore. I just get `classDefNotFound Persistor` in the tests because it static initialize the *EntityManager* which can't connect cause of the new `persistence.xml` -- or at least it's my opinion, because the stacktrace is not really helpful. But, after `maven -> update project...` in eclipse on the project, `mvn install` works again and the new password is taken (tests run!).

When I want to deploy the project on a remote machine (debian, commandline) I can't ´mvn install` the pulled project, cause after I changed the password in persistence.xml for deployment, it's again the wrong persistence.xml or at least some cached used.
I hope that make it a bit more clear.

**SOLUTION:**
Make sure persistence.xml is placed in src/main/resources/META-INF and not elsewhere. m2e catches persistence.xml from wrong places (in my case, src/main/java/META-INF). So it was basically just a wrong project structure.

Comment: This should be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564684/how-to-fix-error-updating-maven-project-unsupported-iclasspathentry-kind-4?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you can use `mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse` to [regenerate the eclipse project files](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_FAQ) -- hope that sorts you.

Comment: unfortunately it did not work out. after a mvn clean or fresh git pull i cant install.

Comment: What do you mean? you "cant install", edit your question with whatever errors you get and I'll be happy to take a look.

Comment: He is obviously using the [m2e](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) Maven integration for eclipse. That does not harmonize with to the [Maven eclipse plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html) that you mention. I would not use both in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

maven update project from eclipse is different because it will generate a Maven Dependencies class path container

`mvn eclipse:eclipse` generates a Referenced Library Container.