# Openshift Maven not adding any library jar files with maven commands

Tags: java, spring, maven, openshift, paas

I am trying OpenShift PaaS these days. I have a Java cloned openshift project in my local eclipse. When I add Maven dependency , it doesn't add it to project. Below is my Maven added dependencies for Spring

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

But even after doing mvn install My web.xml says it could not find jar files.
[image]

It adds Jar in target folder while build but not in workspace as in picture

Comment: Resolved , I looked up RedHat Link https://www.openshift.com/blogs/spring-mvc-3-on-jboss it says ." Right-click over the project, go to menu and click Update Maven Project " this step gave error like  "Updating Maven Project". Unsupported IClasspathEntry kind=4" Which was on Stackoverflow on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065093/an-internal-error-occurred-during-updating-maven-project-unsupported-iclassp 
 by Vjeetje

Comment: Hi kumar I am also deploying my spring app ; did u provide your pom.xml along with exploded jar to git repository from where you are pushing your app?

Comment: To add it in workspace you have to update your project to maven project else you can add dependencies one by onein build path by selecting from variable and deployment

Comment: I only pushed pom.xml . It will automatically take jars before deploying .