# How to fix error "Validating org/eclipse/m2e/wtp/MavenWtpPlugin"

Tags: eclipse, maven, websphere, m2e, m2e-wtp

I have Eclipse (Juno SR2) with both M2E (1.3), M2E-WTP (0.17) and WebSphere Dev Tools for v.8. The problem started after Websphere Dev tools installation. It says in error dialog : "Validating" "org/eclipse/m2e/wtp/MavenWtpPlugin".

In Eclipse logs it turned out to be NoClassDefFoundError

```
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Validating <module name here>".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/m2e/wtp/MavenWtpPlugin
```

Does anyone had some luck in solving this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing class is in fact there, plugin `org.eclipse.m2e.wtp`. Started to dig  in the IBM WAS Dev Tools. 
The problem originates from `com.ibm.etools.maven.javaee.core` plugin. 
Checked MANIFEST.MF under `\plugins\com.ibm.etools.maven.javaee.core_1.1.0.v20130522_1924\` and it turned out there is some strange version range bundle dependency on `org.eclipse.m2e.wtp;bundle-version="[1.0.0,2.0.0)";resolution:=optional`. The plugin `org.eclipse.m2e.wtp` version is not even close to version `1.0.0` and resolution is optional, so made some changes to conform the bundle resolution:

```
...,org.eclipse.m2e.wtp;bundle-version="[0.1.0,2.0.0)";resolution:=optional,...
```

Started Eclipse with `-clean` argument, and refreshed all Maven projects in the workspace.

This seems to do the trick for me. You may still get

```
"Updating Maven Project". Unsupported IClasspathEntry kind=4
```

but there is a fix for this already here ["Updating Maven Project". Unsupported IClasspathEntry kind=4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564684/how-to-fix-error-updating-maven-project-unsupported-iclasspathentry-kind-4)